# JavaScript to Ruby translator framework

Tags: javascript, ruby, translate

Anyone know of such a framework? Preferably an open-source project, but first, anything at all. A google search proved fruitless.

Comment: what on earth are you talking about?

Comment: oh I see, that green check box under the answer vote widget. thanks for calling my attention to it, but it was a little unnecessary to vote me down for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenderlove works on something like that: https://tenderlovemaking.com/2007/04/15/converting-javascript-to-ruby-with-rkelly.html

But the last version was in the 2009 on the rubyforge and maybe it's dead

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the link in the other answer is broken, but I have written [another translator](https://jarble.github.io/transpiler/javascript/js_transpiler/test_parser.html#%7B%22inputText%22%3A%22%5Cndef%20add(a%2Cb)%20%5Cn%20%20%20%20return%20a%2Bb%5Cnend%22%2C%22inputLang%22%3A%22ruby%22%2C%22outputLang%22%3A%22javascript%22%7D) to convert a small subset of JavaScript into Ruby.

This a function in JavaScript:

```
function add(a,b){
    return a+b;
}
```

and this is the translator's output in Ruby:

```
def add(a,b) 
    return a+b
end
```